# BNA network start failure

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am trying to implement a multi-organization network with fabric kafka with TLS enabled mode. I added currently one organization with Kafka multi orderer mode. The network starts well and peers are joined to channel. I am having .bna file which and trying to install its working fine. After that, I am trying to start a network it fails.

```
✖ Starting business network definition. This may take a minute...
Error: Error trying to start business network. Error: Failed to receive commit notification from localhost:7051 for transaction '76d7dfd29df7c65442c6fe8ea87898f53604c539910b985c2bb89b3fea0f10a0' within the timeout period
```

My connection profile JSON is given below

```
{
    "name": "example",
    "x-type": "hlfv1",
    "x-commitTimeout": 300,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "1500",
                    "eventHub": "1500",
                    "eventReg": "1500"
                },
                "orderer": "1500"
            }
        }
    },
    "channels": {
        "mychannel": {
            "orderers": [
                "orderer0.example.com",
                "orderer1.example.com",
                "orderer2.example.com"
            ],
            "peers": {
                "peer0.org1.example.com": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                },
                "peer1.org1.example.com": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org1.example.com",
                "peer1.org1.example.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.org1.example.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "orderer0.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:7050",
            "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:7053",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer0.example.com"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIICNTCCAdugAwIBAgIQLin25y/L/T+Sxt70ly8EiDAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjBsMQsw\nCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEWMBQGA1UEBxMNU2FuIEZy\nYW5jaXNjbzEUMBIGA1UEChMLZXhhbXBsZS5jb20xGjAYBgNVBAMTEXRsc2NhLmV4\nYW1wbGUuY29tMB4XDTE4MTEyNjA0NTMwMFoXDTI4MTEyMzA0NTMwMFowbDELMAkG\nA1UEBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExFjAUBgNVBAcTDVNhbiBGcmFu\nY2lzY28xFDASBgNVBAoTC2V4YW1wbGUuY29tMRowGAYDVQQDExF0bHNjYS5leGFt\ncGxlLmNvbTBZMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHA0IABPztNJPGPaHwTh0eqUpx\nEqIyG5H3gqcuyTyMXra7AvLklgnUaz8gjylBqYkgX/aWe45Ct2DhOF+kOVd4LcSa\nUOajXzBdMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBpjAPBgNVHSUECDAGBgRVHSUAMA8GA1UdEwEB\n/wQFMAMBAf8wKQYDVR0OBCIEIPTcirmpxvqGwramOon7IAwRcqwnra3M1g244gXX\nwIG7MAoGCCqGSM49BAMCA0gAMEUCIQDypo+APwuqv23mosPcLnz4W+BW4C26Vk75\nt1iRSc8h2QIgL8vMHTB7Q+FQDaZDDw+dEv2I+utGLkSoDxTbeZ8taZA=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            }
        },
        "orderer1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:8050",
            "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:8053",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer1.example.com"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nt1iRSc8h2QIgL8vMHTB7Q+FQDaZDDw+dEv2I+utGLkSoDxTbeZ8taZA=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            }
        },
        "orderer2.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:9050",
            "eventUrl": "grpcs://localhost:9053",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer2.example.com"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nt1iRSc8h2QIgL8vMHTB7Q+FQDaZDDw+dEv2I+utGLkSoDxTbeZ8taZA=\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            }
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nnbxNC5sUyTCqvxWhfw==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            }
        },
        "peer1.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:8051",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org1.example.com"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nnbxNC5sUyTCqvxWhfw==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "https://localhost:7054",
            "caName": "ca.org1.example.com",
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting error as follows in newly created container.

[image]

If anyone knows please help me

Link for exact replica of project: [Karthik-Venkatesh/Hyperledger-Multi-Organisation-Network](https://github.com/Karthik-Venkatesh/Hyperledger-Multi-Organisation-Network/tree/master)

Comment: My first thoughts would be around your kafka setup. A failed to receive commit notification implies that the start request was simulated successfully and the proposals sent to the orderer but then the peer has not committed a block with those proposals to the blockchain so it could be that the orderer hasn't sent the blocks to the peer for validation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the above question, the issue found in the configuration of the following environment variables in peer containers of the organization.

```
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION
```

Default it uses the configuration `CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true`, I removed the environment variable.

If you want manually define `CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER`, please correctly configure the above environment variables.